# Collect Apache Ignite node logging on centralized master node

Tags: java, logging, ignite

I'm not sure I fully understand the purpose of the GridLogger injection in Apache Ignite. For example I'm using Log4j2. What is the advantage using GridLogger on all nodes over just using a static Logger class like this:

```
protected static final Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger();
```

All nodes will write to node-local files anyway, right? Or is GridLogger actually able to write all cluster logging into one centralized file on one master server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GridLogger is just a wrapper around any supported logger that is used by Ignite internally. Injecting of it gives you ability to log to the same file as Ignite and with the same configuration, even if you did not setup any logger. Anytime you can use your own logger as you used to.

There is no any log aggregation with GridLogger.